# Should I replace this bottom plate?

Tags: bathroom, repair

I am undertaking a bathroom remodel and lo and behold found some water damage against an interior wall. It is not extensive and doesn't run through the entirety of any of the studs or plates. I'm thinking I should be fine with a wood putty repair rather than replacing this but appreciate a second opinion from someone more knowledgeable than myself. [image]

Comment: Is it a load bearing wall?

Comment: Both answers below are good ones, but I wonder why you'd prefer to "fix" it rather than replace it. The "fix" (putty approach) when you are doing a full remodel seems..... like someone who didn't care would do. If it's your place or you respect your customer, do them or yourself a solid and replace a chunk. The floor is a definite, but while you are in there you can reinforce as need be. Is this near the edge of the tub? These are the locations you want SOLID SOLID SOLID SOLID, as the corner of tubs are what tend to sag, thus, water damage like you see here.

Answer (score 2):

There's only one way to fix rotten framing, in my opinion, and it doesn't involve putty. It's with new framing. Cutting out and replacing a short bit of plate (or just a portion of it) isn't difficult. It may not even be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you could make a repair rather than replacing the bottom plate. I would recommend the 2-part repair putty (it's like auto-body filler) because it bonds better, is easier to shape, and can be nailed/drilled/screwed into without crumbling so much.

Ensure that all rotten wood is dug out/removed. I use a product by Minwax called **Wood Hardener** prior to using the filler in situations like this, it soaks into surrounding wood fibers and firms them up and helps prevent further dry-rot.